# add download image link to the in title fancybox 1.3.4

Tags: jquery

I'm using *Fancybox 1.3.4* and I want to be able to add a download link in the title for whatever image is currently being viewed. How can I do this without switching to *Fancybox 2.0* because that`s not an option for my situation.

This was my attempt:

```
_format_title = function(title) {

        var $el = $('.thumb-link');
        var url = $el.attr('href');
        var dl = $el.data('dl');
        var link = '&nbsp;<a class="download-link" href="' + url + '" download="' + dl + '">Download</a>';


        if (title && title.length) {
            if (currentOpts.titlePosition == 'float') {
                return '<table id="lightbox-title-float-wrap" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td id="lightbox-title-float-left"></td><td id="lightbox-title-float-main">' + title + '</td><td id="lightbox-title-float-right"></td></tr></table>';
            }

            return '<div id="lightbox-title-' + currentOpts.titlePosition + '">' + title + link + '</div>';
        }

        return false;
    },
```

I created those variables and then added the `+title+link+` but it will not get the currently viewed title it will on get the first anchors `href`. the variable `dl`'s data comes from a data attribute I have in the `html` with images file name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i ended up figuring it out myself anyway. I thought id post the answer just in case anyone else ran into the same issue. I used already defined variable and function that fancybox 1.3.4 had to fix.

Here is the finished code:

```
_format_title = function(title) {
        downloadLink = '&nbsp;<a class="download-link" href="' + currentOpts.href + '" download="' + currentOpts.href + '">Download</a>';

        if (title && title.length) {
            if (currentOpts.titlePosition == 'float') {
                return '<table id="lightbox-title-float-wrap" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td id="lightbox-title-float-left"></td><td id="lightbox-title-float-main">' + title + '</td><td id="lightbox-title-float-right"></td></tr></table>';
            }

            return '<div id="lightbox-title-' + currentOpts.titlePosition + '">' + title + downloadLink + '</div>';
        }

        return false;
    },
```

Created a new variable:

```
downloadLink = '&nbsp;<a class="download-link" href="' + currentOpts.href + '" download="' + currentOpts.href + '">Download</a>';
```

Then I added the new variable to title:

```
return '<div id="lightbox-title-' + currentOpts.titlePosition + '">' + title + downloadLink + '</div>';
```